# Not able to access the second level of child component in angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a page. In HTML of the page, a child component selector has been used. This child component is a form. Inside this child component, I have used several other child components.

So, it is something like this:

Parent Page

```
  |
```

Child(A) component

```
    |

   Child(B), Child(c), Child(d)
```

How should I approach this problem.

I'm using ionic 5 and angular 10.

Page:
[Parent Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrOCb.png)

Child(A):
[Child A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA3zr.png)

Page and Child(A) relationship:
[Child A is present in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIqM5.png)

Child(B):
[This is child B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9sXL.png)

Child(B) present in Child(A):
[Child B in Child A's HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxWzN.png)

Error which I'm getting:
[This is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NINf.png)

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried so far and what you are trying to achieve.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I' have edited my questions description, please help.